# Camel stored procedure call can't use variables?

Tags: stored-procedures, apache-camel, firebird

Trying to build a generic REST-to-stored-procedure bridge along this approach:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/{procedure}")
    .to("sql-stored:${header.procedure}()");
```

Which gives the error

```
org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.ParseException: Encountered " <SIMPLE_EXP_TOKEN> "${header.procedure} "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting:
    <IDENTIFIER> ... 
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.SSPTParser.generateParseException(SSPTParser.java:370)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.SSPTParser.jj_consume_token(SSPTParser.java:308)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.SSPTParser.parse(SSPTParser.java:27)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.TemplateParser.parseTemplate(TemplateParser.java:41)
    ... 38 more
```

I saw examples using header variables in `sql-stored` at many places but always when binding variables. How could I set the name of the stored procedure dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send the message to a dynamic endpoint. The destination uri will depend on the ${header.procedure} content.

From Camel 2.16 onwards you can use "toD" to tell Camel that your destination endpoint is dynamic.

There is more information here http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html and here http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html

Comment: I missed this feature, tried to use set the endpoint with `simple()` also but it did not work.. this did, thanks!